# What's the difference between these two ways of initializing an array?

Tags: python, list, initialization

```
matrix = [[0]*1005]*1005
```

and

```
matrix = [[0 for _ in range(1005)] for _ in range(1005)]
```

I found if i using the former to initial array, and run `matrix[1][1] = 1` it will set the second column in every row to 1. And the second performed as i wished. I can't figure out why?

Comment: possible duplicate of ["Least Astonishment" in Python: The Mutable Default Argument](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-in-python-the-mutable-default-argument)

Comment: Oops. That wasn't the question I wanted to select.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`[[0] * 1005] * 1005` will create an array of 1005 *references* to an array with 1005 zeroes. They're all the same reference, and so changing one will change all the others. You can shorten your working code to this, though:

```
matrix = [[0] * 1005 for _ in range(1005)]
```

<sub>This is pretty much the only warning anybody ever gives you about the list multiplication syntax, actually :)</sub>

Comment: Can you give me a link about this in python reference. Actually, what does it means about `[0]*1005`. Thanks.

Comment: @user674199: http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq. See s * n: "n shallow copies of s concatenated".

Comment: `[0] * 1005` is ok since integers are immutable.

Answer (score 3):

Just to expand on whats already been said

```
a = [[0]] * 5
print a # [[0], [0], [0], [0], [0]]
a[0][0] = 1
print a # [[1], [1], [1], [1], [1]]
```